# Oracle command-line tools on Linux

Tags: linux, oracle

What is the equivalent of *oradim* on Linux?
Does Oracle even provide anything like that for Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not alternate command for oradim.
On Linux simply manually create new environment for new instance.

On Linux (and Unix) there are no Services (at least not as on Windows), but only processes, and these processes are automatically activated when the instance is started, and removed when the instance is shut down.

To start a new instance, say `newsid`, you create an `initnewsid.ora` file, then

```
$ export ORACLE_SID=newsid
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Sep 5 16:38:30 2006

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SYS@newsid SQL> startup nomount pfile=<complete path for initnewsid.ora>
```

If you are running Red Hat (or CentOS), you could copy and change one of the scripts in `/etc/init.d` and add it to your service list by using `chkconfig`. This can help you with automagically starting your database after a reboot of the machine.

It does seem that you are fairly new to the Linux platform though, so please ask an administrator to help you with those scripts (nofi).

Comment: I'm not new to Linux or Oracle, it's just the first time that I'm constrained to creating an instance without any kind of user interface and all Oracle "assistants" are graphical.

Comment: Arguably, a GUI interface to some Oracle-specific /etc/rc.d services could be considered equivalent.

Comment: it actually works pretty straight forward.
create pfile
startup nomount
create spfile
create database
and that's it